# update database during git in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, git

Is there any way to update `database` content, while working with `git`, except `seed`?

I pushed the code with some `database` update, Is there any way to `pull` the database too, from other end?

Comment: Where did you push the code? to github? And you made your database record changes locally?

Comment: yes,. i did changed it locally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you made some changes in your code and your database locally and then pushed your changes to your github repo. Then, you want to pull those changed files from somewhere else.

The answer is `NO`. Github is for code sharing and collaboration.In general, you can't update your local database changes to github. You can push the code/files to github and those can be pulled from anywhere given they have proper permission.

One way of sharing your local database with someone is else is using some cloud server where you can upload your local database and then someone else can download that from there.

here is a gem [taps](https://github.com/ricardochimal/taps) which can be used for this purpose.

Comment: what is the way to update the database? by seeding, it's possible, right?

Comment: I think the best way of doing this to use a cloud server where you can upload your database. See my updated answer.

Comment: Actually yeah, you can dump the data as seed data or write to JSON and then push to github. But, those are not scalable solution and should not be done in production.